# Performing shutdown actions when the pod is the last in a cluster

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, openshift, distributed-computing

### TL;DR

How can I tell that the Spring Boot application that is currently receiving a [graceful termination](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination) in a Kubernetes (Openshift) environment is the last surviving pod in a clustered application in order to perform some *active* logout logic for the last survivor?

### Full question

I am working on a banking application that requires exchanging MQ messages with brokers in order to enable payment services. The protocol requires that *one application* (emphasis on one) logs in to the remote broker in order to establish a *session* that will be kept alive using heartbeats on the queues.

This protocol allows for a *logout* exchange to inform the broker that we are not accepting messages, and this is being used during few maintenance windows over the year. This way, the broker knows that my application won't be available for processing messages. Ideally, the application should be available 24/7.

Normally, in a Spring Boot application, from the coder's perspective, I would simply add a shutdown hook, or even better an `@EventListener(ContextClosedEvent.class)` to perform clean logout. This is expected to work fine when dealing with testing environments and developer's laptop running the IDE.

But... a production-grade application for a real-world bank runs clustered for high availability and load balancing. For that, the project consists of a microservices-based application running on Openshift, where this Spring Boot application can be autoscaled on multiple pods.

As one may guess, the state is handled by a database or a fast distributed cache, and simply speaking any node can process a message, in particular if pod A sends a login request to remote party, the response may be processed by pod B running the same application. This works fine with properly-written code

So here comes my issue: pods can be recycled, and the whole cluster of pods counts as one entity for the *session* purpose. When a pod is shut down for scale-down, it must not issue the **logout** message to the queue, at least if there are any survivor pods to handle further messages.

But, during a maintenance window, I expect the last pod being shut down should be the one handling the logout protocol to tell the other party "Hey, I'm going to be taken offline and nobody is left listening", process outstanding messages, and die.

#### My work so far

Currently, I have come with only one simple-enough possible solution: an **user-issued** logout. The application would expose a REST endpoint that, if invoked by the user with `Postman` or `curl`, informs the counterparty to shut traffic down. This must precede the actual Kubernetes takedown procedure, otherwise the session (in the eyes of the counterparty) become stale.

Another complex solution is to manage clustering in application code, e.g. storing information about available nodes in a table/cache, so that during graceful shutdown a pod first queries the data source to check how many pods are left alive, and if self is the last it's time to perform an active action

Example

```
if (sql.run("select count(*) from active_pods where last_heartbeat > datetime-:timeout") <=1){
    protocol.logout();
}
```

Am I missing something? Can I detect a total cluster shutdown when Openshift starts killing my pods?

Answer (score 1):

I started writing a novel trying to answer this question, but in an attempt to write something more concise I'm just going to hit the critical points:

1. Don't attempt to have a pod act differently if it's the only pod. In a distributed system like Kubernetes you are never going to be able to reliably determine if a pod is the last pod. There are too many race conditions, especially in the case of something like a network partition. But, perhaps even more importantly, it just violates the paradigm of Kubernetes where all Pods are supposed be "cattle": independent and unaware of constructs "above" them like replicasets and deployments.
2. If you absolutely must have some kind of construct that looks for failure conditions and sends a logout message to the queue, it's better to have a standalone watchdog. (Or you could incorporate the watchdog into the operator, if you have one.) How the watchdog watches is up to you:  e.g. push heartbeat messages into the queue and check for replies, use the K8S API, or you could use your idea for an external database/cache to maintain heartbeats. They all have dangers for false positives, but by keeping the watchdog external and as simple as possible you are going to have a much better time than trying to incorporate this logic into the application pods. (After all, lots of scenarios for "zero pods" would involve crashloops and kills, rather than clean shutdowns.)
3. I do not know of any hook you can catch in the case of cluster shutdown. Fundamentally, the process of stopping pods is the same no matter the cause for stopping the Pod. (And the Pod shutdown is just simple TERM and KILL signals.)
4. But I suspect that you what you already have in progress is the best solution. Have an application specific shutdown process. Where some external entity sends a "quiesce" message to the Pods, shuts down the Pods, and a logout message to the queue. (Perhaps not in that order.) And then trigger this process via whatever application rollout process you have (a preSync hook in ArgoCD/OpenShift GitOps, a pipeline stage, an Ansible playbook, ...)